# Port forwarding on Parallel Desktop

Tags: port, port-forwarding

My situation is like this. I have a Windows 7 VM run by Parallel Desktop, on which I run ASP.NET on localhost:1240 (Visual Studio development server). Is it possible from my host machine (OSX 10.9) to be able to test the website using port forwarding, i.e. accessing the site in OSX from http://:

Thank you in advance.

Comment: YOu should be able to access it by the internal ip for instance if the win7 machine ip is 192.168.1.100 http://192.168.1.100:1240 should wok you should for internal systme need port forwarding

Comment: I think it's possible but can you elaborate on how to do that? Supposed my VM's IP is 10.211.55.3, I opened Parallels preference and add a rule (1234, 10.211.55.3, 1240) but still cannot access from 10.211.55.3:1234 either

Comment: if you added a rule it sounds like you changed ti port to 1240, try 10.211.55.3:1240 internal system do not require port forwarding, on my virtual machines i access them y there internal ip and port, i would suggest settng parallel desktop ip range to your mac range so if your mac is 192.168.2.10 set ip range of parallel desktop to 192.168.2.200-192.168.2.250 the problem might be your on another subnet to your virtual machine the other option is to change your mac subnet mask to 255.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Parallels (v12) by configuring it either one of two ways:

Either use Bridge Networking instead of Shared, which will bring your VM to the same router subnet.

Or my preferred method, configure Parallels to do port forwarding by right mouse clicking on the Parallels Icon in the Dock and choosing Preferences. From there choose `Network`. Then choose `Shared` and configure the "Port forwarding rules".